# How do I prove that the given system is globally asymptotically stable, using Lyapunov analysis?

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-system, lyapunov-functions

How do I prove that the given system is globally asymptotically stable, using Lyapunov analysis?

\begin{equation}
\left.\begin{aligned}
\dot{x_1} &= x_2 \\
\dot{x_2} &= -\frac{x_1}{1 + x_2^2} \label{eq:q2}
\end{aligned}\qquad\right\}
\end{equation}

Comment: Are you familiar with Lyapunov functions? And what have you tried yourself?

Comment: I have tried general quadratic functions, such as (x1^2 + x2^2), but a term xy remains and I can't conclude properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to get the Lyapunov function in the form
$$
V=\frac12x_1^2+g(x_2)
$$
so that
$$
\dot V=x_1x_2+g'(x_2)\frac{-x_1}{1+x_2^2}
$$
so that one would get a usable result with $g'(x_2)=x_2(1+x_2^2)$, integrating to,for example, $g(x_2)=\frac14(1+x_2^2)^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was taking something similar to g(x2) but it was constant and I was stuck. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @SampleTime : Then consider $V-V(0)$ to get the normalized value. I prefer the completed square for its simplicity.

Comment: @SampleTime : Could you elaborate? How to get a negative value from $V-V(0)=\frac12x_1^2+\frac12x_2^2+\frac14x_2^4$?

Comment: @LutzL You are correct, nice! I made an error when writing down the equation, sorry for the confusion.